# Error in Login to API Manager Publisher using admin previleges:

Tags: wso2

Getting Following Error when trying to log-in into API Manager- Publisher module, i can log-in to Administrator(Carbon) using admin privileges but cannot log-in to Publisher.

HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[https: //localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin] java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your admin username/password? If so, you have to provide correct username/password in the api-manger.xml at  configuration

Comment: No, the Admin credentials are not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer after long time the question was asked!

I faced the same error. I realized that I was connected to my clint's VPN before I started wso2 api manager. As soon as I disconnected from the client's VPN, I was able to login to store and publisher. I guess there is some security issue related to networks when it comes to Wso2.

Please check if this was the case with you too.

Hope it helps someone!